# How do you add two int arrays with different lengths?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, int

I've been working on a Java lab that wants us to have the user enter two digits up to 50 digits long and add them together. I've successfully been able to complete everything except for when the two arrays have a different length. I've been toying around with the code for a while, but I keep coming up short. Can anyone look at the code for this and have any suggestions? Thanks!

```
int[] number1 = new int[input1.length()];
int[] number2 = new int[input2.length()];
int[] answer = new int[input1.length()];

if(number1.length > number2.length){
    number2 = new int[number1.length];  
    for(int i = 0; i < number2.length - number1.length; i++){
        number2[i] = 0; 
    }
}

if(number2.length > number1.length){
    number1 = new int[number2.length];  
    for(int i = 0; i < number1.length - number2.length; i++){
        number1[i] = 0; 
    }
}
```

Whenever I add, say 120 and 12, it says there's an Array out of bounds error.

Comment: Java will initialize your int array with all values equal to zero. So you're effectively doing nothing with your for loops. Im not sure what you're trying to accomplish with your code but I would suggest re-evaluating the problem and trying again

Comment: I assume you are simulating arithmetic. If the user enters 9 and 9, how will the answer fit in an array of size 1?

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry, that's just the portion of the code relating to the problem. The rest of my code accommodates for say 9 + 9 to make it equal 18, it's just the part where if the digits are different size I have a problem.

Comment: considering your two if statements, your for loops never executed; `if(number2.length > number1.length)` then `number1.length - number2.length` is less then 0 thus `i` is never `<` then result of subtraction. same goes for the 1st `if` statment.

Comment: Are you creating a calculator? Does the total of 18 result in 1 and 8 in different elements of an array?

Comment: Are you trying to separate the numbers into single digits? Like 120 becomes an `int[]` of `{1, 2, 0}` ?

Comment: @Bohemian Well, if the user enters 120 & 120, it will equal 240. It works for all addition for arrays of the same length. But if the user enters 120 and 12, I want to make it so the 12 turns into 012 so they become the same length and performs the correct addition.

Comment: @peeskillet Yes but I didn't put that part in there, maybe I should just put all of my code in

Comment: if you can put all you code in - that would be useful...

Comment: 120 is not an edge case. What is the result if the user enters 9 and 9? Is it one value of 18 or two values 1 and 8?

Comment: @Bohemian It stores it in the answer array as {1, 8} and displays it as 18 to the user

Comment: Is it a requirement to use `Array` ? Looks like you are making complicated something trivial.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan yes because it's supposed to accept inputs of up to 50 digits long, so if someone put in a number over 19 digits long you wouldn't be able to just add the two ints.

Comment: `answer` is only large enough to hold the number of digits in `input1`.

Comment: If the user entered `{9, 9, 9}` and `{8, 8}`, should the answer be `{1, 0, 8, 7}` (not `{9, 17, 17}`)? Ie you're building a calculator?

Answer (score 2):

First thing you need to do is get the numbers into an int array. Do that by Splitting string to char array.  Then convert to int array. Then add.

```
String input1 = scanner.nextLine().trim();    <-- get input as String
String input2 = scanner.nextLine().trim();

char[] array1 = input1.toCharArray();         <-- split to char array
char[] array2 = input2.toCharArray();

// convert to int array
int[] intArray1 = new int[array1.length];     <-- declare int array
int[] intArray2 = new int[array2.length];

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    intArray1[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(array1[i]));  <-- convert to int
}
for (int i = 0; i < array2.legnth; i++){
    intArray2[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(array2[i]));
}

// check which one is larger and add to that one
if (intArray1.length > intArray2.length){
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray2.length; i++){
        intArray1[i] += intArray2[i];                  <-- add values
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray1);     <-- print largest
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray1.length; i++){
        intArray2[i] += intArray1[i];
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray2);
}
```

If you want to get the number representation printed instead of an array, instead of the System.out.println(), use this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i : intArray1){
    sb.append(String.valueOf(i));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

So 123 and 12 will print out 233

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your code is, you try to pre-append (push from head) 0s to the shorter array. Look at the first if-block. The length of number1 is larger than what of number2. Thus, number2.length - number1.length is negtive. Then, in the for loop, i < number2.length - number1.length is always ture. (I am not familiar with java. I guess array's length is an integer.) And you still have to copy the rest of array.

The correct code should be,

```
   if(number1.length > number2.length) {
       int[] number3 = new int[number1.length];

       for(int i = 0; i < number1.length - number2.length; ++i) {
           number3[i] = 0; 
       }
       for(int i = 0; i < number2.length; ++i) {
           number3[i + number1.length - number2.length] = number2[i];
       }

       number2 = number3;
   }
```

BTW, the second if-block should be changed in a similar way. Perhaps, java provides an API link insert(0, 0) for array object. It will be easier to implement.

Comment: Your code seems like it would work, but when I implemented it, it still gives the same error.